# Checking if FTP server drive space available through health monitoring on Zeus Load Balancer / Stingray Traffic Manager

Tags: load-balancing, zeus

I am trying to find out if the Zeus Load Balancer (now renamed Stingray Traffic Manager) can send out a notification if the FTP server it's trying to connect and transfer files to to is full or approaching a defined threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default.
There is also no defined standard to get this information via FTP protocol.

You could implement your own monitor and let it run a custom script which gathers this information (if this is implemented in your FTP server installation).
But this would be periodic monitoring, it wouldn't throw that notification when connecting, but whenever the threshold is reached.

To be honest, I wouldn't put this alerting into Zeus but rather in a dedicated alerting infrastructure.